Adding Crossencoder inside a function impact performance, why?
Below is a fastapi endpoint with crossencoder of mxbai-re-ranker insider the fucntion
@app.post('/rank')
async def rank(request_data: RankerPredictionRequest):
    ranker_model = CrossEncoder("mixedbread-ai/mxbai-rerank-large-v1",device="cuda:0")
    query = request_data.query
    documents = request_data.documents
    results = ranker_model.rank(query, documents,return_documents=True,convert_to_numpy=False)
    resp = modify_data(results)
    return resp

which took 3x more time to repond, when compared to calling the model outside the function
ranker_model = CrossEncoder("mixedbread-ai/mxbai-rerank-large-v1",device="cuda:0")
@app.post('/rank')
async def rank(request_data: RankerPredictionRequest):
    query = request_data.query
    documents = request_data.documents
    results = ranker_model.rank(query, documents,return_documents=True,convert_to_numpy=False)
    resp = modify_data(results)
    return resp

I can't understand why this is happening.
I was expecting similar response time in both cases.

Loading the model is a very compute intensive operation. In the first example, each time the /rank endpoint is called, the model is loaded. In the second example, you load the model once at startup, and then continue to reuse that model each time you call /rank. The second approach is almost always preferred.
